# Equivalente ao LIKE em PHP

Tags: php

Como comparo duas strings em PHP da mesma forma do LIKE em mysql.
Por exemplo:

"PARA" seria igual a "PARALELO", "PARALLAX", "PARALELEPIPEDO", "PARAMETRO" ...
pois possui o mesmo inicio.

Mas independente da forma, gostaria de fazer idêntico ao LIKE.

Comment: "igual" ou "possui"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode-se usar expressões regulares para emular o comportamento do `LIKE` no PHP:

```
<?php

function like($needle, $haystack)
{
    $regex = '/' . str_replace('%', '.*?', $needle) . '/';

    return preg_match($regex, $haystack) > 0;
}

var_dump(like('rod%', 'rodrigorigotti'));   // bool(true)
var_dump(like('%tti', 'rodrigorigotti'));   // bool(true)
var_dump(like('%gori%', 'rodrigorigotti')); // bool(true)
var_dump(like('%lala', 'rodrigorigotti'));  // bool(false)
var_dump(like('lala%', 'rodrigorigotti'));  // bool(false)
var_dump(like('%lala%', 'rodrigorigotti')); // bool(false)
```

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar a função [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) que é usada para encontrar a ocorrência de uma string dentro de outra

```
$valor = "PARALELEPIPEDO";
if (strpos($valor,"PARA") !== false) {
    echo "Encontrou";
}
```

Utilizando expressões regulares - [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)

```
if(preg_match("/PARA/", $valor) {
    echo "Encontrou";
}
```

Utilizando [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-count.php)

```
if (substr_count($valor, 'PARA') > 0) {
    echo "Encontrou";
}
```

Pergunta similar no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a função [str_pos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Por exemplo:

```
if ( strpos("paralelepipedo", "para") !== -1 ){
    //seu código aqui
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`/**
 * like
 * procurar em string 
 * @param string $procurar
 * @param string $texto
 * @param boolean $case - false nao verificar maiuscula e minuscula
 * @param string $regex - fazer regex manual
 * @return bool
 */
function like(
    string $procurar,
    string $texto,
    bool $case = true,
    string $regex = ''
) {
    if ($regex == '') {
        $ini = (preg_match("/\A%/", $procurar) > 0) ? '/' : '/\A';
        $fim = (preg_match("/%\z/", $procurar) > 0) ? '' : '\z';
        $fch =  $case ? '/' : '/i';
        $procurar = str_replace('%', '', $procurar);
        $procurar = str_replace('/', '\/', $procurar);
        $regex = $ini .  $procurar . $fim . $fch;
    }
    return preg_match($regex, $texto) > 0;
}`

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).